# How to block SFTP remove operations with Apache MINA SSHD

Tags: java, apache, apache-mina, apache-sshd

I am trying to create a custom sftp server using Apache Mina SSHD. My code so far:

```
 SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
        sshd.setPort(PORT_NUMBER);
        sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Paths.get("keys/private_key.ppk")));

        SftpSubsystemFactory factory = new SftpSubsystemFactory.Builder()
                .build();


        factory.addSftpEventListener(new BasicSftpEventListener());

        sshd.setSubsystemFactories(Collections.singletonList(factory));
        sshd.setShellFactory(new ProcessShellFactory("/bin/sh", "-i", "-l"));
        sshd.start();
```

As you can see, I implemented my own SftpEventListener:

```
public class BasicSftpEventListener implements SftpEventListener {

    @Override
    public void removing(ServerSession session, Path path) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Removin");
    }

    @Override
    public void removed(ServerSession session, Path path, Throwable thrown) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("removed");
    }
```

When I want to remove file, it executes my removing and removed listeners, BUT the remove operation proceeds and the file is deleted.

Is there a way how to stop this from happening?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block delete actions, you will need to interrupt the flow of the `removing` method with an exception. This will tell Mina to stop and not remove the file. I would recommend using `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` for this:

```
@Override
public void removing(ServerSession session, Path path) throws UnsupportedOperationException{
    throw new UnsupportedActionException("Removing files is not permitted.");
}
```

Comment: well this is one way, but i dont think throwing exception to interrupt flow is good idea. Seems like only "nice" way to do it is extend some classes and override behavior.